# How much impact do CSS pseudo elements as overlays that cover the whole page on page load have on SEO?

Tags: seo, css

I have created a page transition where on page load for the fraction of a second a whole page is covered with a CSS pseudo element, which then transitions to go into the background.

Do search engines have troubles reading data? Or are there any other negative side effects of this?

Comment: Google Search actually looks for content shift, so it may have some impact.  But I am not an expert at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable impact would be to your CLS (Content Layout Shift). It's a metric that Google uses to determine how much a page changes once content is visible.

If your CLS is too elevated, search engines may rank you lower.

Try a few validators to check if your website is affected:

- https://web.dev/measure/
- https://pagespeed.web.dev/
- https://gtmetrix.com/

Comment: I have tested my page on many sites and there is no to very less CLS, according to pagespeed insights it’s in the green. I was more afraid of search engines not being able to read the info on the page but that seems to not be a problem. Thank you for you answer.